# How to only render `PluginDocumentSettingPanel` if there are children

Tags: block-editor, conditional-content

I want to use the `PluginDocumentSettingPanel` similar to how the `InspectorControls` component works, where I can add my own controls from different parts of the application. But if there aren't any controls (meta fields, input controls, etc) for a certain post type for example, I'd like to not show the setting panel at all.

Here is what I have so far, but I'm not sure how to make it conditional based off if any of the slot fill's children will be rendered. In this example, a post type that supports "author" would show the settings panel, but a type that does not support it should not show the panel at all.

**SitePostOptions.js**

```
import { createSlotFill, withFilters } from '@wordpress/components'
import { PluginDocumentSettingPanel } from '@wordpress/edit-post'
import { registerPlugin } from '@wordpress/plugins'

const { Fill: SitePostOptions, Slot } = createSlotFill('SitePostOptions')

SitePostOptions.Slot = Slot

export { SitePostOptions }

registerPlugin('plugin-document-setting-panel-site-post-options', {
    render: withFilters('site.postOptions')(() => {
        return (
            <PluginDocumentSettingPanel name="site-post-options" title="Options">
                <SitePostOptions.Slot />
            </PluginDocumentSettingPanel>
        )
    }),
})
```

**example.js**

```
import { PanelRow } from '@wordpress/components'
import { createHigherOrderComponent } from '@wordpress/compose'
import { PostTypeSupportCheck } from '@wordpress/editor'
import { addFilter } from '@wordpress/hooks'
import { SitePostOptions } from './SitePostOptions.js'

addFilter('site.postOptions', 'site/post-options/example', createHigherOrderComponent((Block) => (props) => {
    return (
        <>
            <Block { ...props } />
            <PostTypeSupportCheck supportKeys="author">
                <SitePostOptions>
                    <PanelRow>
                        Example test
                    </PanelRow>
                </SitePostOptions>
            </PostTypeSupportCheck>
        </>
    )
}, 'withExample'))
```

Comment: You mention "if there aren't any controls for a certain post type" what do you mean by that? What do you mean by children? Child blocks? The question doesn't make sense, try to make it clearer and avoid ambiguity or implying things and instead state it clearly, even if it seems obvious to you or patronising